# IS ISNULL() specific for integers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This has been bothering me with my coding continuously and I can't seem to google a good workaround.

I have a number of columns which are data type `nvarchar(255)`. Pretty standard I would assume.

Anyway, I want to run:

```sql
DELETE FROM Ranks WHERE ISNULL(INST,0) = 0
```

where `INST` is `nvarchar(255)`. I am thrown the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Un' to data type int.

which is the first non null in the column. However, I don't care for this showing me the error means it's not null? - I just want to delete the nulls!

Is there something simple I'm missing.

Any help would be fab!

Comment: `DELETE FROM Ranks WHERE INST IS NULL`

Answer (score 3):

An expression may only be of one type.

Expression `ISNULL(INST,0)` involves two source types, `nvarchar(255)` and `int`. However, no type change happens at this point, because `ISNULL` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) to return the type of its first argument (`nvarchar`), and will convert the second argument to that type if needed, so the entire original expression is equivalent to `ISNULL(INST, '0')`.

Next step is the comparison expression, `ISNULL(INST, '0') = 0`. It again has `nvarchar(255)` and `int` as the source data types, but this time nothing can stop the conversion - in fact, it must happen for the comparison operator, `=`, to even work. According to the [data type precedence list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), the `int` wins, and is chosen as the resulting type of the comparison expression. Hence all values from column `INST` must be converted to `int` before the comparison `= 0` is made.

If you

> just want to delete the nulls

, then just delete the nulls:

```sql
DELETE FROM Ranks WHERE INST IS NULL
```

If for some reason you absolutely have to use `isnull` in this fashion, which there is no real reason for, then you should have stayed in the realm of strings:

```sql
DELETE FROM Ranks WHERE ISNULL(INST, '') = ''
```

That would have deleted `null` entries *and* entries with empty strings (`''`), just like the `WHERE ISNULL(INST, 0) = 0` would have deleted `null` entries *and* entries with `'0'`s if all values in `INST` could have been converted to `int`.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the error is due to the fact SQL is trying to compare to incomparable values, hence the conversion error. I mean seems obvious but its the same as saying 0=‘0’ - does not compute lol

Comment: Fantastic, I was formatting the statement wrong! Really appreciate the quick reply, I can get on with it :)

Comment: @DougCoats Actually my entire initial explanation was wrong. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

With `ISNULL(INST,0)` you are saying: If the string `INST` is null, replace it with the string 0. But 0 isn't a string, so this makes no sense.

With `WHERE ISNULL(INST,0) = 0` you'd access all rows where `INST` is either NULL or 0 (but as mentioned a string is not an integer).

So what do you want to achieve? Delete all rows where `INST` is null? That would be

```
DELETE FROM ranks WHERE inst IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, otherwise you risk deleting rows with valid `inst` values (e.g. = `'0'`).